# Xamarin.Froms MVVMCross loading modal view

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

My team have been struggling with this for few days.
We are porting a swift app over to Xamarin.Forms using MVVMCross
(This is our first play with Xamarin.Forms)

Our app consists of 4 main viewcontrollers and we have numerous modals views that appear as a 'FormSheet' (so they appear NOT full screen and can be sized). In swift we embed each modal view within a navigation controller.

We are struggling how to do this behaviour in Xamarin.Forms

We have created our main view controllers and can switch using

```
await _navigationService.Navigate<...ViewModel>();
```

What we can't do is either load the modal view (so they appear as modal view) or load the view in a new navigation window (again as a modal view)

Answer (score 1):

In order to open a page as a modal you must add the attribute to forms page on code behind

```
[MvxModalPresentation(WrapInNavigationPage = false)]
public partial class YourModalView : MvxContentPage<YourModalViewModel>
```

I would highly recommend you to check the [presentation attributes from MvvmCross for Xamarin.Forms](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/xamarin.forms/xamarin-forms-view-presenter)